# Java SQL Prepared statement with *ANY* criteria

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

Meet ps, a simple PreparedStatement that does the job:

```
PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ref=? AND time=>? AND time<?");
```

I need to add 3 optional criteria (C1,C2,C3). For clarity, they may be required on not based on runtime parameters.
 Brute force tells me I can write 9 prepared statements to cover all possibilities. But what I would really like to write is more something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ref=? AND time=>? AND time<? AND C1=? AND C2=? AND C3=?;
```

and use a trick like setInt(5, "*ANY*") or ignoreParameter(5) before executing the statement
Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option of using a framework, doing it yourself or doing some sql tricks. E.g. JPA has a [CriteriaBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html).

Otherwise split up your query in a static and a dynamic part. Depending on your dynamic part you would have to do the binding. You would have

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ref=? AND time=>? AND time<?
```

as your static part and add `AND C1 = ?`only when needed.

For SQL options you could add 3 more parameters and set them to `0` or `1`.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ref=? AND time=>? AND time<? 
AND (CHECKC1 = ? OR C1=?) AND (CHECKC2 = ? OR C2=?) AND (CHECKC3 = ? OR C3=?);
```

However I wouldn't call it a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You'll need to compose your query dynamically.

No need to create all the combinations, though. Just appending an additional `"and c1 = ?"` to the query if the parameter is defined is OK.

There are APIs that do this for you. See http://www.jooq.org/ for example.